# Connect to a WiFi-Direct Network with a device which doesn't have the WiFi-Direct feature

Tags: wifi-direct

Can an Android device which doesn't have the WiFi-Direct feature connect to other WiFi-Direct networks as a peer connected to a Group Owner (GO)?